# OS error messages when running multiple q/kdb+ servers on the same database in separate Docker containers

Tags: docker, kdb

I've been getting unpredictable error messages like

```
./2016.12.19/ccbar/padjm. OS reports: Operation not permitted
```

I'm using multiple Linux `q` sessions that are dockerized and running in separate containers opened on the same database directory containing partitioned tables, and have found that such errors will go away when restarting the other `q` sessions and their containers.

Could Docker be causing some sort of locking of files? And would there be any way to release the lock? Or perhaps there is some other cause to  this behavior? Am I not supposed to run multiple `q` sessions on the same database directory with partitioned tables? And would there be any methods to get rid of this error without restarting the `q` sessions?

Comment: this is probably a symptom of the docker containerization itself which I have no experience in. The error is from the OS and not kdb. Perhaps something needs done in order to share the hdb directories between containers?

Comment: I've seen similar "operation not permitted" errors before but usually that's in relation to permission issues on the underlying files in the database